# Better formula for multiple IF Statements in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I need some assistance in my formula, I have an IF statement that I need to wrap in another IF Statement, and it appears this isn't allowed as I keep getting errors. Can anyone assist?

My current formula =IF(K2=0,Q2/O2,K2) of which yields column R.

What I need is IF(K3=0,Q3/O3,K3) is greater than P3/O3 then TRUE: P3/O3 FALSE: IF(K3=0,Q3/O3,K3).

EDIT: R3 should be 3.699999

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=MIN(IF(P2/O2=0,1E+99,P2/O2),IF(K2=0,Q2/O2,K2))
```

[image]

Comment: This works for the one cell, it yields 0 on every other column.